# How do I query an ODBC DSN in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, odbc, dsn

My specific problem is related to querying an Oracle database via Oracle ODBC driver, but I'm having trouble in the general case as well.

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that is a simple SELECT, which queries a table in a remote database. There is a DSN configured for the remote database.

The statement I have tried to run in SQL Server Management Studio looks like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET(...) as a
```

This returns an error: The OLE DB provider "foo" has not been registered.

Can anyone explain the proper usage of this function?

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190312(v=sql.105).aspx

Is 'provider' synonymous with 'driver' or 'data source'? If driver, can it be ODBC drivers or does it need to be specifically OLE DB?

More generally, is this the correct way to query via an ODBC DSN?

Comment: Do you run a 32-bit/64-bit machine? Providers or drivers must align to how MSSQL is installed. Check odbcad32.exe ('C:\WINDOWS\System32' or 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64') and see if Oracle drivers appear.

Comment: @Parfait I suspect there is some of that going on, but even supplying the name of an ODBC driver that I know is installed for a given architecture, it's not working. This is why I am unclear on whether that function accepts ODBC drivers or specifically OLE DB ones.

Comment: Did you check the listed installed sources on machine as mentioned? That error suggests a bit version incompatibility.